# my script.js and mail.php do not match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I'm at the end of my rope and was hoping someone could help me out.  I took over for someone and have been trying to have my form send via ajax POST but the mail.php I've been using does not send even though I get a 200 OK.  I did a test on conetix and it sent but I must be missing something.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is the relevant script:

```
     $("#send").click(function(){

                var valid = '';
                var isr = ' is required!</p>';
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var mail = $("#email").val();
                var messaggio = $("#message").val();

                if (name.length<1) {
                    valid += '<p>*Valid name'+isr;
                }
                if (!mail.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
                    valid += '<p>*Valid email address'+isr;
                }
```

and here is my php:

```
<?php

/// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'xxx@xxx.com';
$subject = 'Contact Us Form Submission';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: xxx@xxx.com' . "\r\n";


?>
```

Again, any help would really keep me from tearing my eyes out.

```
                if (valid!='') {
                    $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#response").html(valid);

                    $('#send').removeClass('normal').addClass('error-button');
                    $('#send').val('');

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#send').removeClass('error-button').addClass('normal');
                        $('#send').val('send');
                        $("#response").fadeOut("slow"); 
                    }, 3000);                         
                }

                else {
                    var datastr ='name=' + name + '&mail=' + mail + '&messaggio=' + encodeURIComponent(messaggio);
                    setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",1000, $('#send').val('wait...'));
                }
                return false;
            });
```

}(jQuery))

```
        function send(datastr){
            $.ajax({    
                type: "POST",
                url: "phptest.php",
                data: datastr,
                cache: false,

            success: function(html){
                $('#send').removeClass('normal, error-button').addClass('send-email');
                $('#send').val(''); 
            }

            });
        }
```

Comment: check for errors, check your console

Comment: I'm getting no errors on my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data string looks like this:

```
'&mail=' + mail
'&messaggio='
```

While your PHP is grabbing this:

```
$_POST['email'];
$_POST['message'];
```

'mail' != 'email' and 'messaggio' != 'message'

Comment: Thank you for the information, but can you clarify what you mean?  What shold it be grabbing?

Comment: I believe you meant I should change the 'email' to mail and 'message' to 'messaggio'.  I tried this but it still does not send.  Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: @redsoxburns You need to make them match.  Either both as `email` or both as `mail`.  One is setting the variable to a value, the other reads it.